# Error with XP-PEN G430S tablet on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mouse, tablet, graphics-tablet

I'm using a XP-PEN G430S tablet on Ubuntu and I've noticed the following error:

- When I plug it into my notebook, the usb mouse (which is already plugged in) becomes dead; it resumes working after plugging the tablet out and plugging the mouse out and in again. However, the touchpad of the notebook works well.

So, it seems that the two input devices cannot coexist. Why is that? Is it a problem with the driver installation?